Find a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$.
This is an exercise from book of proof. The solution on the textbook confuses me, so I am reaching out for help here.
He show the bijection using transitivy. His proof as follows.
First he shows the bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1)$:

Consider the subset $X=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq[0,1]$. Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1)$ be defined as $f(x)=x$ if $x\in[0,1]-X$ and $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n+1}$ for any $\frac{1}{n}\in{X}$. So it's easy to check that $f$ is a bijection.

I am confused here. Why does he find a subset of $[0,1]$ as $X$, and then construct a piecewise-defined function. I don't know why and how does he construct such a function.
In the second step, he uses a similar procedure as above.

Let $Y=\{1-\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq[0,1)$, and defined $g:[0,1)\rightarrow(0,1)$ as $g(x)=x$ if $x\in[0,1)-Y$ and $g(1-\frac{1}{n})=1-\frac{1}{n+1}\in{Y}$. As in the case of f, it's easy to check that $g$ is a bijection.

It confuses me as the same as the first step. I totally have no idea why choosing such a subset and how does the piecewise-function come out.
Combining the above 2 steps, using the transitivity, he shows that the composition of $g$ and $f$ is a bijection.
Can you explain the proof for me?

Let's just consider the first step. As you observe, the second step is very similar to the first step, so once you understand that one, you should understand both.
The author is constructing an infinite sequence of numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$ that all lie within the unit interval, with $x_1 = 1$. As in the first stage of the Hilbert hotel, if we map $x_1$ to $x_2$, $x_2$ to $x_3$, $x_3$ to $x_4$, and so forth, we leave a "hole" at $x_1$ without having to create one at "the other end" (since there is no other end "at infinity"). In the case of the hotel, this allows us to accommodate an extra guest; in the case of this problem, this allows us to remove $x_1 = 1$ from the range of the mapping.
Here, the author uses the sequence
$$
x_k = \frac{1}{k}
$$
yielding $1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots$. However, the author could just as easily have used
$$
x_k = \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}
$$
yielding $1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, \ldots$. The argument will work the same for both sequences (and infinitely many others, as long as they lie within the unit interval and don't repeat).
Of course, there is more to the unit interval than the sequence of numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$, because that sequence is countable by definition, and the unit interval is not. So if we denote the set $X \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots\}$, we define the mapping as the one that maps $x_1$ to $x_2$, $x_2$ to $x_3$, $x_3$ to $x_4$, and so on, and leaves all the other numbers untouched. In symbolic terms,
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x_{k+1} & \text{if $x \in X$ and $x = x_k$} \\
x       & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
For example,
$$ f(1) = 1/2 $$
$$ f(1/2) = 1/3 $$
$$ f(1/3) = 1/4 $$
$$ f(2/3) = 2/3 $$
$$ f(1/4) = 1/5 $$
$$ f(2/4) = f(1/2) = 1/3 $$
$$ f(3/4) = 3/4 $$
$$ f(1/\pi) = 1/\pi $$
and in general,
$$ f(x) = x $$
if $x$ is irrational, or even rational but simply not the reciprocal of a positive integer.
